# Drawing tables and arrows connecting them

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know whether it is possible to draw something like the example below with `ggplot2`. If not, could you please direct me to an appropriate tool to accomplish that in `R`? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The package `dm` might be a better solution than ggplot. `dm` is a great package for data modelling tasks and data modelling visualization on relational databases.

Comment: Thanks, Nicolás! I had already spotted the `dm` package, but it seemed to me, in order to draw an ER diagram, dataframes or database tables should be previously created, and I am looking for a tool for creating hypothetical ER diagrams (without a previously created database).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes, of course it's possible. It depends a bit on what your use case is on how much automatisation you want to put into it. The tricky bit is clearly the arrow bit, and on trying an automated approach it became slightly convoluted, so I'll leave that to you - just showing one principle way to get this in ggplot2.

```r
library(tidyverse)
ls_tbl <- replicate(3, data.frame(label = paste0("Field", 5:1)), simplify = FALSE)
## make the data frames for tables and rects
ls_df <- lapply(seq_along(ls_tbl), function(i){
  df <- rbind(ls_tbl[[i]], paste0("Table", i))
  df$y <- seq_len(nrow(df))
  df$x <- i
  df_rect <- data.frame(xmin = i-.2, xmax = i+.2, ymin = min(df$y)-.5, ymax = max(df$y)+.5)
  y_seg <-  (df$y[length(df$y)] + df$y[length(df$y)-1])/2
  df_seg <- data.frame(x = i-.2, xend = i+.2, y =y_seg, yend = y_seg)
  setNames(list(df, df_rect, df_seg), c("text", "rect", "seg"))
})
## draw arrows, this can be automated based on the position of fields and tables
## that's not suuuuper straight forward, so I won't do that here
arrow_df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 3), xend = rep(2, 2), y = c(5, 5), yend = c(2, 4)) %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(xend > x, x + .2, x - .2), 
         xend = ifelse(xend > x, xend- .2, xend + .2))

## now plotting fun
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = bind_rows(map(ls_df, "rect")), color = "black", fill = NA,
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) +
  geom_segment(data = bind_rows(map(ls_df, "seg")), aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend))+
  geom_text(data = bind_rows(map(ls_df, "text")), aes(x, y, label = label)) +
  geom_segment(data = arrow_df, arrow = arrow(type = "closed"), 
               aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, @tjebo! Very impressive solution!

Answer (score 2):

I have meanwhile found a way with `DiagrammeR` and `graphviz ports`:

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz("
digraph G {
    graph [layout=neato overlap = true]     
    node [shape=plaintext]

    a [label=<<TABLE BORDER='0' CELLBORDER='1' CELLSPACING='0'>
                           <TR><TD>Table 1</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='11'>Field 1</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='12'>Field 2</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='13'>Field 3</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='14'>Field 4</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='15'>Field 5</TD></TR>
              </TABLE>> pos = '0,0!'];

    b [label=<<TABLE BORDER='0' CELLBORDER='1' CELLSPACING='0'>
                           <TR><TD>Table 2</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='21'>Field 1</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='22'>Field 2</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='23'>Field 3</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='24'>Field 4</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='25'>Field 5</TD></TR>
              </TABLE>> pos = '1.5,-0.5!'];

    c [label=<<TABLE BORDER='0' CELLBORDER='1' CELLSPACING='0'>
                           <TR><TD>Table 3</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='31'>Field 1</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='32'>Field 2</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='33'>Field 3</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='34'>Field 4</TD></TR>
                           <TR><TD PORT='35'>Field 5</TD></TR>
              </TABLE>> pos = '3,0!'];

    a:11 -> b:21;
    c:31 -> b:24;

}")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the `DiagrammeR` package, as it has a lot of options for visualizing information like this. So, for example, you could do the following to do something similar to your example:

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz(" 
      digraph CFA {
      a [label = <<u><b>Table 2</b></u> <br/> Field 1 <br/> Field 2 <br/> Field 3 <br/> Field 4 <br/> Field 5>, shape = rectangle]; 

      node [shape = rectangle]
      T1    [label = <<u><b>Table 3</b></u> <br/> Field 1 <br/> Field 2 <br/> Field 3 <br/> Field 4 <br/> Field 5>];
      T2    [label = <<u><b>Table 1</b></u> <br/> Field 1 <br/> Field 2 <br/> Field 3 <br/> Field 4 <br/> Field 5>];

      {rank = same; a T1 T2}

      # Connect nodes with edges and labels
      a -> T1[dir=back]
      T2 -> a[dir=forward]
       }

      ")
```

Output

[image]

You can see [Richard Iannone's webpage](https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphviz_and_mermaid.html) for more in depth information on how to manipulate the layout, different shapes, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew Gillreath-Brown! The crucial part of the graph I would like to draw is that the arrows are not only to connect tables, but specifically the fields (the words in tables). I did not know about `DiagrammeR`, but I have recently found that `DiagrammeR`/`Graphviz` have `ports` that allow to join, by an arrow, the specified pair of fields. I have to study its `ports`.

Comment: @PaulSmith Oh okay, yeah that's a bit more complicated than what I show here. I'd be interested in the solution that did too (which is why I just bookmarked this question too)!

Comment: If I find a solution, I will share it with you, @Andrew Gillreath-Brown.

Comment: @ Andrew Gillreath-Brown: my solution is now posted.